# Flutter is using provider to load data is the right option?

Tags: flutter

So i have a situation where i make an request from the server for one widget.
The widget is at the home page, lets take the worst case where the data is huge and the request take time.
Should i change the widget to stateless and make a provider which i will initialize before i run the app with all the initial data?
Should i contain all the data of the widgets at home page and deliver theme as props, i miss understood the concept of managing the state here, I'm coming from vue and i try to write my first app and I'm struggling how to structure my data through the routes.
I would like if some one explain or give a good source that show how to initialize data from third party
before the home page reload.
Which approach is better getting all the app data before the app reload or request data every time from db with cash

Answer (score 0):

State management in flutter is a topic with hot debate, there is no best approach, but using one for sure is better than nothing. However there are exceptions to this, sometime adding a state management to a simple part of the app is not recommended. Regarding your case, it can be done without a full state management solution, by using a `FutureBuilder` for example. Or it can be also done with `Provider`, `BloC`, `Redux`...

As a naïve general rule, if the state is to be passed down the widget tree more than 1 or 2 levels, you should probably start looking for a state management solution depending on the use case. As I already have said, there is no one best state management solution.

Also, it is ok to use more than one as long as you know what you are doing but in general as a best practice it is not recommended to use more than one.

---

Regarding the second part of the question, it totally depends on the nature of the data and it's size. If the data is big and it is a small possibility that the user will be using all of it, it is better to load it on demand, also loading all the data upfront will increase the cost on the backend side.

However getting the data upfront, makes the experience more seamless to the user (Not waiting while using the app, but he will have to wait a little extra when the app is first loading).

So as you see it is a balance. Also it is good for the server and the app to do some type of caching since it helps reduce the work on the server side and decrease the bandwidth usage on the phone.

An example for caching images you can use Cached Network Image [Link](https://pub.dev/packages/cached_network_image), example from flutter cookbook [Link](https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/images/cached-images).

Comment: ty I'm using cashing in my server side i think i will have big data so i try to balance it tell me if i have advertisments for my home page sohuld i request it every time i enter the home page of use provider as a casing

Comment: Deciding whether to request a data when on a certain route is not related to provider or any state management solution in general, it only depends on your data. In some cases you have a data is constantly changing and you must update every time, and sometimes the opposite. As I have said it depends on your data.

Answer (score 0):

You might have seen this approach in other apps as well which is to show a splash screen until the data has been loaded and ready to be shown. This approach is mostly used by apps which got large data to load at the start. You could achieve this in your initState like the following.

```
  @override
  void initState() {
  loadData();
 splashTimer = Timer(Duration(seconds: 4), () {
  _goToHome();
});
super.initState();
}
```

Comment: Although this might produce the desired behavior, you must check if the data was actually loaded before you call `_goToHome();` since OP mentioned that he wants to do all the loading before opening the home screen.

Comment: True Sir, you're right. Instead of waiting for 4 seconds, we should wait until the data is being loaded.

Comment: ty for you answers. what if i am moving between my routes i can show the last data the widget had or it most rebuild and in this case using provider will make it more reusable?